# Send a file to the server using axios in react app

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I'm using axios within React to try and send a file to the server. Can someone please show me what I'm doing wrong here. There's no error. The `form` variable returns an empty object. I'm completely stumped.

Path: `React submit call`

```
handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.props.uploadProducts(supplier_id, this.fileInput.current.files[0]);
}
```

Path: `uploadProducts`

```
export const uploadProducts = (supplier_id, file) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const form = new FormData();

  form.append('my_field', 'my value');
  form.append('my_file', file);
  console.log(form);

  axios
    .post('http://localhost:3000/products', form, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    })
};
```

Path: `Server`

```
router.post('/products', async function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('res', req.body);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

FormData API wont return your values by console logging it directly. It has some helper functions, some of then iterators, to extract its values. check more: [formData MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)

your axios post doesnt seem to match your router end point. axios is also a promise library, hence you use `then` and `catch` to handle resolve and reject actions.

```
  axios
    .post('http://localhost:3000/upload/supplier/products', form, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    })
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

if you define your function as `async` you could use `await` and wrap in a try catch block:

```
 try {
   const response = await axios
    .post('http://localhost:3000/upload/supplier/products', form, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    })
   console.log(response)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e) 
  }
```

Comment: `axios post doesnt seem to match your router end point`, this was a typo. I've tried the suggestion and I get the same outcome. Empty object. Is it still `req.body` on the server

Comment: are you using some middleware to handle form-data? there is [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#readme) which handles that exact kind of data.

Comment: So the problem turned out to be I needed to install the express package `const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');`